# How to update a single field in a Contentful entry?

Tags: javascript, contentful, contentful-management

Need help updating a field in a CF entry. It is a dropdown field without a default value.

I tried to do that by getting the entry from the CF environment, setting the corresponding field and updating it like this:

```
        client.getSpace(spaceId)
        .then((space) => {space.getEnvironment(environment)
            .then((environment) => {environment.getEntry('1234567890')
                .then((entry) => {
                    entry.fields = {
                        state: {
                            'en-US': 'Arizona'
                        }
                    }
                    return entry.update()
                })
            })
        })
```

By doing so, the `state` value gets updated, but the other existing field values are deleted.

The Contentful documentation for content update states the same here: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/introduction/updating-content, but I cannot find a way to implement their suggestion.

How do I update the `state` value without losing all the other fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```js
entry.fields = {
  state: {
    'en-US': 'Arizona'
  }
}
```

You replace the whole `fields` object by the new one containing only one key: `state`.
Instead of setting `entry.fields`, you should set `entry.fields.state`

Example:

```js
client.getSpace(spaceId)
    .then(space => space.getEnvironment(environment))
    .then(environment => environment.getEntry('1234567890'))
    .then(entry => {
        entry.fields.state = {
            'en-US': 'Arizona'
        }
        return entry.update()
    });
```

*Also*: I changed the way you use `.then()`. One of the benefits of Promises is that you don't have to nest callbacks. Here you are nesting callbacks. You can chain `.then()` calls to make your code more readable, as I did in the sample above. See: [Aren't promises just callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks)